# How to include jpcap library?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jpcap

How to include **jpcap** library on Netbeans or Eclipse installed in windows 7 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no 64 bit version of JpCap(which was last updated in 2007). You can use jnetpcap which works with both 32 and 64 bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar to your working project by right clicking on any class file of the project or the project and then 
**Buildpath -> Configure Buildpath -> Libraries -> Add External Jars** -> find the location of jar

Comment: but i can't find a jpcap for (64-bit) and when i include the regular version of it i got that error when compiling.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jpcap.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform